# flask-security unable to send email

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

When I try to send email using flask-security it takes a while and then fails with following error on the screen

---

Something went wrong !
Server timed out or sent incomplete response

Click here to try again. (Perhaps you meant to use HTTPS instead of HTTP?)

If that still doesn't work, please Issue a bug report.

---

My flask settings are:

```
# Flask Security Configuration
SECURITY_CONFIRMABLE = True
SECURITY_REGISTERABLE = True
SECURITY_RECOVERABLE = True
SECURITY_TRACKABLE = True
SECURITY_PASSWORD_HASH = 'bcrypt'
SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT = '4f6d0251-7927-45e5-a211-8b8411deca22'
SECRET_KEY = 'longtextlongtext'

MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.zoho.com'
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USE_SSL = True
MAIL_USERNAME = 'xxxxx'
MAIL_PASSWORD = 'xxxxx'
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: _Maybe_ you could try putting http:// before the mail server domain or if that doesn't work https:// as the message suggests?

Comment: I am trying to connect from Cloud9 servers, if there is problem from the other side.

Comment: Can you try to find a more detailed error message, pls? If you know the line the error occurs it it easier to fix...

Comment: @palsch that didn't help much, it was refused outright as not supported protocol for mail communication.

Comment: Tried changing provider to my gmail account and that seems to progress further (to other error, but this time is is gmail based error so that's fine) so looks like c9 or zoho has a filter built in to prevent connection.